# Problemas em inserir dados em base de dados

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados

Boas, eu estou aqui com um problema pois insiro os dados todos mas não me guarda na base de dados. Alguém aqui sabe qual o problema com os seguintes códigos:

```html
<form action="php/RegistoFederados.php" id="formF" method="post">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Sexo</td>
<td><select name="sexo" id="sexo" required>
 <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
 <option value="M">Masculino</option>
 <option value="F">Feminino</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nome Completo</td>
<td><input type="text" class="txtfield" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo" required ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Data de Nascimento</td>
<td><input type="date"  name="dataNasc"  required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BI ou CC</td>
<td><input type="text" class="txtfield" name="bi" maxlength="8" placeholder="BI ou CC" required onblur="Vbi()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Nº licença de Federado</td>
<td><input type="text" class="txtfield" name="Nfederado" id="nf" onblur="Vfed()" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td><input type="text" class="email" name="email" placeholder="maratonajomara@gmail.com" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Telemovel</td>
<td><input type="text"  id="tlm" class="txtfield" name="telemovel" maxlength="9" required onblur="Vtlm()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Morada</td>
<td><input type="text" class="txtfield" name="morada" required></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Levantamento de dorsais</td>
<td><select name="localdorsal" id="localS" required>
 <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
 <option value="loja">Loja Jomara</option>
 <option value="PUA"> Quiosque do Conhecimento PUA</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Metodo de Pagamento **</td>
<td><Select name="pagamento" required>
 <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
 <option value="Dinheiro">Dinheiro</option>
 <option value="Transferência">Transferência Bancaria</option>
</select></td>
</tr>   
<tr>
<td>Equipa</td>
<td><input type="text" class="txtfield" name="equipa"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Prova</td>
<td><select name="prova" required>
 <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
 <option value="45 km">Meia-Maratona 45 KM</option>
 <option value="70 km">Maratona 70 KM</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Almoço</td>
<td><select name="almoco" required>
 <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
 <option value="1">Sim</option>
 <option value="0">Não</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="submit" class="Sinscricao" value="Submeter Inscrição"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<p>**Nas inscrições se o pagamento for por transferência bancária, deverá ser enviado o comprovativo por e-mail com o nome completo do atleta</p>
</form>
```

```html
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","jomara");
 
 $sexo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sexo']);
    $nome = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nome']);
 $dataNasc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dataNasc']);
    $bi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['bi']);
 $nf = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nfederado']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $telemovel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telemovel']);
    $morada = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['morada']);
    $local_dorsal = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['localdorsal']);
    $pagamento = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pagamento']);
    $equipa = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['equipa']);
    $categoria = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['categoria']);
    $almoco = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['almoco']);
    $pago = 0;
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO registofederados(sexo,nome,dataNasc,bi,numero_federado,email,telemovel,morada,local_dorsal,pagamento,equipa,categoria,almoco,pago) VALUES('$sexo','$nome','$dataNasc','$bi','$nf','$email', '$telemovel', '$morada', '$local_dorsal', '$pagamento', '$equipa', '$categoria', $almoco, $pago)";
 
 if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
 echo "<script>
             alert('Inscrição realizada'); 
             window.history.go(-2);
     </script>";
 }
 else{
  echo "<script>
             alert('Inscrição não realizada'); 
     </script>";
  header('Location: ../federados.html');
  }
?>
```

Comment: Sua tabela é realmente "registofederados" não era pra ser registrofederados?

Comment: coloca dentro do `else` o seguinte código `echo mysqli_connect_error();` e comenta o `//header('Location: ../federados.html');`, então coloque aqui o resultado.

Comment: isso ajudou imenso, obrigado, o problema estava em    $categoria = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['categoria']); que era suposto estar $categoria = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prova']);  mas agora que testei, aparece a pagina aparece em branco

Comment: @KayoBruno sim a tabela chama-se mesmo "registofederados"

Comment: Obrigado o vosso apoio mas já resolvi o problema (a minha burrice) tinha me esquecido de inserir um campo na tabela

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro verifiquem sempre se os dados da base de dados coincidem com os dados do php. Depois verifiquem sempre se os dados que estão no php são os mesmos que os do form na pagina de html. Foi esse o meu problema e estou a responder à minha pergunta para não haver outra pessoa a passar pela burrice que passei.